# Working of the Chain Rule in Calculus

Tags: derivatives, calculus

I came across a proof of the **chain rule** in a book called "Calculus Made Easy" by Silvanus P. Thompson. It said that the rule works because we essentially **multiply and divide** by another small change in another function (usually represented as *du* for a change in function *u(x)*).

I.e.$$\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac {dy}{du}.\frac {du}{dx}$$

But when I tried to confirm this with my Physics teacher, he said that we can't actually explain it in that way because, *du* separated from *dy* or *dx* has no meaning as $\frac {d}{dx}$ is considered as a **whole entity** or an **operator** rather than a **fraction**. Please help me out with a clear explanation regarding this.

Also, please say whether there is any more **direct** approach other than the **indirect** (I suppose, it's indirect because we make up an intermediate function) chain rule to differentiate function compositions such as $$y=e^{sin x}$$

P.S. I'm just a beginner in the context of Calculus.

Comment: This is off-topic for physics. But a simple appropriate proof of the chain rule for your level can be found here: https://www2.math.uconn.edu/~stein/virtual/Notes/Calculus/chainrule.pdf

Comment: @MattHanson, I do not think this is off-topic in physics. Leibnitz's notation for derivatives is much more popular in Physics than in Math. Unfortunately, most physicists use this notation with a sense of guilt, thinking that it does not have a sound mathematical justification. I could write an answer justifying my claim, but I am tired of answering questions that are in the process of being closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately what you call the indirect method is in fact the most direct method. Here's a link as a review [libretexts](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Calculus_(OpenStax)/03%3A_Derivatives/3.06%3A_The_Chain_Rule)
Although when we're dealing with composite functions we do *seem* to treat them as a sort of fraction ("cancelling" out the du) this is not in fact what we are doing. $\frac{dy}{du}$ is the rate of change of y wrt u and $\frac{du}{dx}$ is the rate of change of u wrt x. They are two different animals.  You are multiplying together two different rates of change to get the overall rate of change.

So you have to write down the steps: Let u = sin(x) and differentiate $y=e^u$ to get $\frac{dy}{du}$ and then multiply by $\frac{du}{dx}$.

Like all things, you'll become familiar with this. That's the thing about math, it's like learning a new sport, you only improve with practice.

Comment: Why do we specifically multiply the rates of change to get the overall one and not any other specific operation?

Comment: @BlackKnight23 If you are running 3 times as fast as Bill and Bill is running twice as fast as Jill who is running at 2mph, how fast are you running?

Comment: @BlackKnight23 Suppose you can make $\$5$ from every pie you can bake, $\frac{dm}{dp}$, and you can bake $10$ pies per day $\frac{dp}{dd}$. Then the amount of money you can make in a day is $\frac{dm}{dd}=\frac{dm}{dp}\frac{dp}{dd}=5(10)=50$ dollars per day.

Comment: Really thanks for such intuitions!